biometrics log, time in and time_out with different shifting schedule
From the given sample table below, i would like to show the daily time in and out of the employees on my database. Employees schedule have different shifting sched.
Sample database table



empno
punch_code
punch_datetime




61
0
2/1/2024 07:40


61
1
2/2/2024 08:03


61
2
2/1/2024 23:46


61
3
2/1/2024 04:05


61
2
2/2/2024 15:33


61
1
2/3/2024 00:04



This is the sample query that i have
select x.empno,
    x.am_in as am_in,
    x.am_out as am_out,
    x.pm_in as pm_in,
    x.pm_out as pm_out,
from(select empno,
    min(case when punch_code = '0' then punch_datetime end) am_in,
    max(case when punch_code = '1' then punch_datetime end) am_out,
    min(case when punch_code = '2' then punch_datetime end) pm_in,
    max(case when punch_code = '3' then punch_datetime end) pm_out
from biometric_log
where punch_code in ('0', '1', '2', '3')
group by empno, punch_date
order by empno, punch_date
) x
group by x.empno, x.am_in, x.am_out, x.pm_in, x.pm_out
order by x.empno;

The problem with the result of this query is the time out of the other shift most specially those having nights shifts is not correct. this is the output:



empno
am_in
am_out
pm_in
pm_out




61
2/1/2024 07:40

2/1/2024 23:46
2/1/2024 04:05


61

2/2/2024 08:03
2/2/2024 15:33



61

2/3/2024 00:04





The desired output would be like this



empno
am_in
am_out
pm_in
pm_out




61
2/1/2024 07:40


2/1/2024 04:05


61

2/2/2024 08:03
2/1/2024 23:46



61

2/3/2024 00:04
2/2/2024 15:33




note: I am using a MySql database.
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you

Hi @isabel what is difference between your actual & desired output ?

poor asking question pattern. You are not improving question pattern day by day.
Please add db sample data set. Share db<>fiddle sample data set ... example : https://dbfiddle.uk/BxKARleh

the difference is the actual output is the time in and out is not correct, the desired is correctly place base on the pm in and am out of the employee on his night and graveyard shift

I see ... are you want output like last table ? am I right ? @isabel

Yes, Exactly. Can you please help?

How we know, when night shift start ? @isabel
How 2/1/2024 04:05 is pm_out time in reality ?

the shifting sched would be from am in to pm out, then change shift to pm in to am out which is night shift, then the graveyard shift pm in to am out

I am sorry for the typo, the pm out should be 2/1/2024 16:05

WITH
cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(punch_code IN (2,3)) OVER (PARTITION BY empno ORDER BY punch_datetime) grp
  FROM test
  ORDER BY empno, punch_datetime
)
SELECT empno, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN punch_code = 0 THEN punch_datetime END) am_in,
    MAX(CASE WHEN punch_code = 1 THEN punch_datetime END) am_out,
    MIN(CASE WHEN punch_code = 2 THEN punch_datetime END) pm_in,
    MAX(CASE WHEN punch_code = 3 THEN punch_datetime END) pm_out
FROM cte
GROUP BY empno, grp
ORDER BY empno, grp;




empno
am_in
am_out
pm_in
pm_out




61
2024-01-02 07:40:00
null
null
2024-01-02 04:05:00


61
null
2024-02-02 08:03:00
2024-01-02 23:46:00
null


61
null
2024-03-02 00:04:00
2024-02-02 15:33:00
null



fiddle

hi, the query is working for the night shift and graveyard shift only, the morning shift is not the same as the result that you've shown.

@isabel The query successfully works on the provided source data. You must edit your question text and expand your data. Provide ALL possible data combinations and desired output for such data. Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.
